# User cannot create file using WebDav with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, webdav

I am using WebDav to copy and paste multiple files into Alfresco.
The problem is that I can only do this with administrator IDs.
When I try to create new files or update existing files as a non-administrator
user, I get the following error:
 HTTP Status Code: 403 caused by: org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.AccessDeniedException: 03300303 Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.

Is there anyway to allow non-administrator IDs to create/update files?

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding the users to a group and using the "invite" action to invite the group as "contributor".

Comment: contributors can only create files & update the files they've created. They cannot update files created by other users. "Collaborator" can also update these files

Answer (score 3):

The Alfresco WebDAV support uses identical permissions to the rest of Alfresco. Nothing special - it's just one of the number of different ways you can interact with the nodes stored in your Alfresco repo.

As such, the user you log in as needs to have both read and write permissions to the folder in question. Typically, that means they need to be a member of the site you want to write to, and need to have permissions higher than Consumer.

As long as the user has write permissions to where you want to write to, they'll be able to make changes using WebDAV.